# Generic smoothness in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ is a dominant morphism of integral $k$-schemes, where $k$ is characteristic $p>0$, and $X$ is smooth. What assumptions do we need for there to exist a dense open $U\subset Y$ over which $\pi$ is smooth?

For example, is it enough for $K(X)/K(Y)$ to be a separable extension?

Comment: It is necessary and sufficient for $K(X)/K(Y)$ to be separable, since that is exactly the condition for the existence of a separating transcendence basis, which in turn is the ``generic'' effect of the Zariski-local description of a smooth morphism as the composition of an etale map to an affine space over the base (i.e., an etale $Y$-map $U \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^n_Y$ for Zariski-open $U \subset X$).

Comment: @nfdc23.  The wording tricked you.  Munchlax wants the open subset to be in the *target* not in the source.  The quasi-elliptic fibrations are counterexamples.  I realize you already know those, but for others: let $Y$ be $\text{Spec}\ k[t]$, and let $X$ be $\text{Spec}\ k[t,z,w]/\langle z^2 - (w^p+t) \rangle$, $p\neq 2$.  Then $X$ is isomorphic to $\text{Spec}\ k[z,w]$, and so it is smooth.  There is a dense open, $V=X\setminus \text{Zero}(\langle z \rangle)$, over which $\pi$ is smooth.  However, the singular locus of $\pi$ surjects to $Y$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Ah, whoops indeed.  So with $k$ perfect of characteristic $p>0$ any regular connected $K(Y)$-scheme $X_{\eta}$ that is generically $K(Y)$-smooth but not everywhere $K(Y)$-smooth spreads out to a counterexample over a dense open in $Y$, and such do exist over $K(Y)$ whenever $\dim Y>0$ since $K(Y)$ is then imperfect. That is, we can find $t \in K(Y) - K(Y)^p$ and then adapt your examples to also allow $p=2$: for any $m>1$ not divisible by $p$ (such as $m=2$ if $p>2$) the integral $K(Y)$-curve $z^m = w^p+t$ is Dedekind and so spreads out to such an $X$ over some dense open in $Y$.